# trying to understand session and cookies - following a tutorial on passport local strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, reactjs, passport.js

I am currently trying to teach myself javascript/node/react and I am following this tutorial: http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#.Vzh2UHUrL0o

Basically, I followed it and have a basic understanding of what the author is trying to do.  However, I don't understand how I am able to persist my logged in state.  When I go into developer tools and inspect resources/cookies, I see this -

```
connect.sid s%3AZfcMh2LatI6Xxol6lTd5_9sO1OmMwjv2.RilGXCviDs5FDS7mc1%2Ftr%2BpqOUq7i26VLha2hKQZKWY    localhost   /   Session 95  ✓
```

I have a basic react app and I want to hook up this API to it using react-native-cookies library (https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/react-native-login) .  However, from the code in the authentication tutorial, where is the cookie actually being set?  How does this all work?

I am not so sure I understand, and I don't feel comfortable moving on.  I hope its okay to ask here .  Thanks